# Как открыть диалоговое окно загрузки при нажатии на картинку?

Tags: php, файлы, изображения, input

Есть картинка (аватарка) при нажатии на неё нужно вызывать `input="file"`, чтобы загрузить картинку и поменять аватарку.

Как это сделать на PHP?

Answer (score 5):

Один из вариантов - использовать CSS, чтобы поменять стиль поля `input`

```css
    input{
        background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        color: transparent; /*Делаем текст прозрачным*/
        border-radius:10px; /*Округление кнопки*/
        text-indent: -99999px; /*Убираем текст*/
        border: 1px solid black
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
<input type="file">
</div>
```

Чуть подробнее о работе:

```php
<?php
// Ищем файл принадлежащий данному юзеру в БД или по названию файла.
// Предполагается, что Вы можете найти файл юзера.
// Нашли url
$ult = "data:image/png;base64,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";
?>
<style>
    input{
        background-image: url(<?php echo $ult;?>); /*Добавляем background кнопки*/
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        color: transparent; /*Делаем текст прозрачным*/
        border-radius:10px; /*Округление кнопки*/
        text-indent: -99999px; /*Убираем текст*/
        border: 1px solid black
    }

</style>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="main">
        <input name="file" type="file">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Сохранить</button>
</form>
<?php
$uploadfile = basename($_FILES['file']['name']); // Получаем имя файла(можем перезаписать его учитывая папку нахождения и логина пользователя.
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile); // Сохраняем файл
```